# Extracting data from unstructured PDF

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I am trying to extract data from an unstructured PDF [here](https://d3fpn4c9813ycf.cloudfront.net/pdfDocuments/WCH_2022_1/WCH_2022_1_ROWMSCULL1-L----------HEAT000100--_C77X5402.PDF)

I am trying to pull the starting info (boat class and start time) but packages such as tabula are not working because the data is not in structured boxes.

Looking to move the info in the PDF into a pandas dataframe. Code I am working with is below:

```
source = 'https://d3fpn4c9813ycf.cloudfront.net/pdfDocuments/WCH_2022_1/WCH_2022_1_ROWMSCULL1-L----------HEAT000100--_C77X5402.PDF'
pandas_options={'header': None}


data = tb.read_pdf(source, pages = 'all', pandas_options={'header': None})
data = data[0]
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
headers = data.iloc[0]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried using PDFTables API and the data looks somehow structured but needs headers fixing and the numeric data looks fine you just need to edit the dataframe so it starts at index 5

Here is the full notebook: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17rbaJn4ea960sX9hJO2Zxt4PtwGelSPC?usp=sharing)

***Note**: use your own API Key :)

Answer (score 0):

If the headers are always the same, it looks like the 4 lines of text before each table.

Here's a possible approach using [pdfplumber.](https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/)

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
from   collections import deque

pdf = pdfplumber.open(...)

for page in pdf.pages:
    lines = page.extract_text_lines()
    last_4_lines = deque(maxlen=4)
    for table in page.find_tables():
        for line in lines:
            if line['bottom'] > table.bbox[1]:
                break
            last_4_lines.append(line['text'])
        print(last_4_lines)
        print(pd.DataFrame(table.extract()))
```

```
deque([
    'Racice, Czech Republic 18 - 25 September', 
    '16 Race Data LM1x', 
    "(Event) Lightweight Men's Single Sculls H1", 
    'SUN 18 SEP 2022 Race 11'
], maxlen=4)

            0             1       2             3       4   ...      8             9       10            11      12
0      Country           TUN    None           IRL    None  ...    None           USA    None           POL    None
1         Rank             6    None             4    None  ...    None             5    None             3    None
2   Dist.\n[m]  Speed\n[m/s]  Stroke  Speed\n[m/s]  Stroke  ...  Stroke  Speed\n[m/s]  Stroke  Speed\n[m/s]  Stroke
3           50           5.3    48.0           5.3    45.0  ...    50.0           5.3    54.0           5.4    50.0
4          100           5.3    43.0           5.2    42.0  ...    47.0           5.3    51.0           5.4    44.0
5          150           5.2    41.0           5.1    41.0  ...    45.0           5.1    48.0           5.2    42.0
6          200           5.0    39.0           5.1    39.0  ...    42.0           4.9    44.0           5.2    41.0
7          250           4.9    38.0           4.9    36.0  ...    41.0           4.8    41.0           5.1    40.0
```